# This page isn’t working error when i refresh the page

Tags: jquery

Am trying to send the user to login page, when he clicks browser back button.

I went to some page  http://example/app/somePage 
here if I refresh the page I am getting page not working error?

My requirement is anywhere user click browser back button should http://example/app/ and if he refresh the current page nothing should happen

```
if (window.history && history.pushState) {
            addEventListener('load', function() {
                history.pushState('',"",''); // creates new history entry with same URL
                addEventListener('popstate', function() {                   
                     window.location='http://localhost:8080/app/';
                 });    
            });
        }
```

Comment: You want  the user to restrict from going back? @smitha

Comment: if user press browser back button should to go login page.. if he refresh the page should be in same page